# Why below query is ' not a single group' function?

Tags: sql, group-by

```
select colA, colB, 
sum( case when colC = 'Y' then count (distinct colD) end ) colD_cnt
from table_sample
group by colA, colB
having colA = 'xxx'
and colB = 'YYY';
```

I need group by colD too?

Comment: The HAVING clause is intended for aggregate function conditions. Move your conditions to the WHERE clause instead! Besides, you don't need the GROUP BY since your query will never return more than 1 row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what you are doing is kinda redundant on the count. I don't know what your problem is, however write it like this and it should work:

```
select colA, colB, 
count (distinct case when colC = 'Y' then colD else null end) colD_cnt
from table_sample
group by colA, colB
having colA = 'xxx'
and colB = 'YYY';
```

I changed your `count` column.

This is how it should be written and it should run fine after that.

Comment: It won't give you the correct count , as distinct will calculate NULL also. (In Line 2 of the query)